# Android development for legacy java web application

Tags: android, mysql, hibernate, tomcat, mobile

I have a legacy `tomcat` `Java` application  (`Spring`, `Hibernate`, `MySQL`) running on Linux (Ubuntu). I want (need) to build an `Android` application utilizing the backend database of existing application. Actually it will be just apilot project to test the things. It will do like display a list of information read from database.

I am .Net developer and totally new here. 
What will be the best approach to go?

> 1. Web app or native `Android` app?
> 2. some service for database access (which, how) or direct connection to DB?

Also, please point out to good resource/books to get me started.

Comment: Connecting directly to the database is not a good solution in most cases because of the unstable network connection of phones. Consider using some kind of backend that enables the phone to get the data from the database via RESTFull JSON services. Web App or native depends on the use cases and the users of the app I think this can not be answered for you on SO.

Comment: @Jansuz, exactly the kind of solution I'm thinking of. Will you please point me to some resources about this.

Answer (score 0):

Android application is more like  desktop, and you application  is spitting out HTML pages. Your options are:
   - provide mobile web interface to your existing appliaction
   - develop new android frontend,  and wrap your existing application with a REST-Service
   - develop android frontend and reuse your persistence and business logic layer.

Big question is,   what exactly you are developing? DO you need your business logic on the mobile device, otr it can stay where it is ( on server )

Comment: Right now business logic will be on the server as I am only trying to read something from server and present it on phone.

Comment: Then you have 2 choices: web frontent optimised for mobile  device ( some javascrip, some CSS) or native UI + exposing your business logic as REST-Service